# Extensions of the field $k((x))$ of Laurent series

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, laurent-series

Let $k((x))$ be the field of Laurent series over some field $k$.
Is it always true that a finite extension $L$ of $k((x))$ is again a field of Laurent series $k'((y))$ over some finite extension $k'$ of $k$?

I guess this does hold for instance if $k$ is a finite field or if $k$ is of characteristic zero but I don't quite understand the degree $p$ extensions of $k((x))$ in characteristic $p$.
Is it still true for arbitrary $k$?

I would be thankful for help and/or a reference.

Comment: When $k$ is algebraically closed of char 0, this is basically Prop 8 of §IV.2 in Serre's Local Fields.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this. But the first vaguely related thing that occurs to me is the fact that in characteristic $p$ we need to go outside the realm of Puiseaux series. For example, what happens when we adjoin $y$ satisfying the equation $$y-y^p=1/x?$$ This gives an Artin-Schreier extension $k((x))(y)/k((x))$. We could thing of $y$ as the series
$$y=x^{-1}+x^{-1/p}+x^{-1/p^2}+x^{-1/p^3}+\cdots.$$ Is that still of the required form?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I guess so. At least it says so in a reference I found in the meantime. If I'm not mistaken, in the example you gave the residue field of $L$ is still $k$, isn't it? So $L$ will be again just $k((t))$ as an abstract valued field.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the response. I just couldn't see a suitable $t$, but I didn't think about it very hard :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a [reference](https://conf.math.illinois.edu/%7Epballen/research/LocalFields.pdf) by Patrick Allen in which one finds for a  field $K$ that is complete with respect to a non-trivial valuation $v$ the following:

> Theorem 5.16. If $v$ is discrete and $K$ has equal characteristic, then $K \cong k((T ))$ as valued fields.